# Moving Applications to External drive

Tags: hard-drive, macos, ssd

My computer is an iMac running High Sierra 10.13.6 and my internal SSD is about full. To free up space I've decided to move my Applications to an external HDD with 2 Gigs. I know I can't move the applications folder but I can select all and move the applications into a new Applications folder on the HDD. I did that and most of the Applications moved but some didn't because they were in use. Ever since I did that my machine has been having problems. Are there steps I should have taken when I moved those applications?

Comment: Did you have SIP enabled when you did this?

Comment: Yes I did. I didn't even think of that.

Comment: Thats good. Just wanted to make sure you didn't **move** a core application.

Comment: What problems occur and when do they occur (Drive in/out/both)?

Comment: Many of apps in the doc no longer show up. When I did a restart I couldn't get to the finder. My screen was blank except for the window of an open app. When I click on screen nothing happens. Some applications on new drive just don't work.

Comment: I moved the files by 'selecting all' on the internal drive and copying them to the external drive. Should I have done more or something different? In my search for answers, some mentioned creating links to the original directory.

Comment: First off I would not suggest saving space this way. Instead, move files and folders (*like the folder of fireworks pictures that you and no one else will ever look at again* :) ) to the external drive.

Comment: Do you have a TM backup (before the transfer)?

Comment: Yes. TM did a backup 2 days ago.  and CCCloner last night.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80717/discussion-between-jbis-and-jmh).